# want to apply setFrameVisibility

Tags: java, android

I want to use setFrameVisibility between two frame layouts to load content. My problem is both pages are showing data at the same time. I want here is when one frame is showing data the other frame hides automatically. Here is my codes from main java file but these codes are not working.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tablecontent_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:src="@mipmap/basic"
            android:background="@null">
        </ImageButton>
    </TableRow>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frametwo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setFrameVisibility (boolean frameOneVisible){
if (frameOneVisible){
    findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    findViewById(R.id.content_frame).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.colourred) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33CCCC"));
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.colourblue) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CC9900"));

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.homepage) {
        Intent homepage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homepage);
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.foodpage) {
        //handle the food page here
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.schedulepage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frametwo
                        , new ScheduleFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.emotionspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new EmotionsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.basicneedspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new BasicneedsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        askBeforeExit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Errors throwns? Nothing happens? And are you in an activity or a fragment?

Comment: Basically both the frame layouts showing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to postInvalidate your frames to update the screen. You can try this :

```
FrameLayout contentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
FrameLayout contentFrameTwo = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo);

if (frameOneVisible){
    contentFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    contentFrameTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    contentFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    contentFrameTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

contentFrame.postInvalidate();
contentFrameTwo.postInvalidate();
```

And using your full main file :

```
FrameLayout contentFrame;
FrameLayout contentFrameTwo;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    contentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    contentFrameTwo = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frametwo);

    setFrameVisibility(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void setFrameVisibility (boolean frameOneVisible){
    if (frameOneVisible){
        contentFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        contentFrameTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        contentFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        contentFrameTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    contentFrame.postInvalidate();
    contentFrameTwo.postInvalidate();
}    

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.colourred) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33CCCC"));
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.colourblue) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CC9900"));

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.homepage) {
        Intent homepage = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(homepage);
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.foodpage) {
        //handle the food page here
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.schedulepage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new ScheduleFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.emotionspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new EmotionsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.basicneedspage) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new BasicneedsFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.exit) {
        askBeforeExit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sir, these codes are not working. giving you full main java file. could you please edit my codes for me. thanks in advance.

Comment: I added my post, you can use the code above. If it doesn't work tell me if there is any errors displayed. By the way, I assumed that the two content_frame and content_frametwo were both FrameLayouts.

And if it works, don't forget to upvote/validate the answer ;).

Comment: Extremely sorry sir, but problem is remaining the same. I have shared my xml file also. As you can see my xml file there is two Frame Layouts. Layout (content_frame) having an ImageButton (basic). That is visible on the homepage of the app.  I tried to load R.id.sechdulepage on the content_frametwo. Now the problem is both the layouts showing data at the same time. That is the main problem.

Comment: Oh right. There are two problems here. First you need to set one of the two layout to the visibility "gone" (to avoid the problem where both layouts are visible). You can do this by adding the line " android:visibility="gone" " to one of the layout. Second you need to use the setFrameVisibility function ! Whenever you want to change the display you can either use setFrameVisibility(true) or setFrameVisibility(false). This can also be used for the first problem (the two displayed at the same time) : you just need to call the function inside the onCreate.

Comment: I have edited my answer. But, to be honnest with you, this isn't right to ask for such thing. It is not my job to write you the code and it doesn't benefit you either since you don't learn anything.

Comment: I agree with you sir, I stuck with this problem for last few days and I could not found the solution that’s why I requested to you edit my codes. Sorry for troubling you. I’ll try your solution and let you know.